# Import Image works on GAE but not in dev_appserver.py

Tags: python, image, google-app-engine, python-imaging-library

I'm using PIL for a GAE application, and have been importing the PIL modules directly using

```
import Image, ImageDraw, ImageChops,
```

The application works correctly with no complaints when uploaded to GAE but when trying to run with `dev_appserver.py` it refuses to import the modules.

Is there a way to force `dev_appserver.py` to recognize them, as GAE obviously supports them?

Comment: Have you installed PIL? It is not a part of the SDK.

Comment: yeah, I can use the PIL code running outside of the dev_appserver.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you have to write `from PIL` in order to import them.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageChops
```

Comment: I tried this approach but was receiving a cannot import name ImageDraw
I ended up editing the `__py27_ALLOWED_MODULES` in `dev_appserver_import_hook.py` and its working for be both locally and on GAE.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have this in your app.yaml?

```
libraries:
 - name: PIL
   version: "1.1.7"
```

How are you doing the import? This works for me:

```
from PIL import ImageChops
```

Comment: Yeah, I had this in as well but it was still throwing import errors
I found a solution editing the module whitelist, see comment above.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to install PIL with this command.

```
sudo easy_install --find-links http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/ Imaging
```

It will require your admin password.